# AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'

Tags: python, typing

Пытаюсь использовать в своем коде `from typing import DefaultDict, List`.

Выдает ошибку:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\graph_examples.py", line 2, in <module>
    from typing import DefaultDict, List
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\typing.py", line 1359, in <module>
    class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\typing.py", line 1007, in __new__
    self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'
```

Модуль `typing` был поставлен (обновлен) с помощью `pip3`: `pip3 install typing`.
Использую `python 3.8.5`, IDE `PyCharm Community Edition 2016.1.5`

Comment: в коде пока только эта строка? если нет, выложите его целиком

Comment: Если у вас версия >=3.5, то `typing` - это часть стандартной библиотеки. Пакет из PyPI предназначен для старых версий. Попробуйте его удалить: `pip3 uninstall typing`, и пользоваться стандартным.

Comment: Мб это поможет https://stackoverflow.com/a/58067012/5909792

Comment: @mkkik, когда пытаюсь удалить, вылетает еще больше ошибок, в конце которых тот же код, что в вопросе

Comment: @mkkik если удалять вручную, то `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing'`

Comment: @Angelika переустановите python. Модуль typing через pip не устанавливайте.

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/typing.py - заберите отсюда оригинальную версию и просто положите в `site-packages`

Comment: @mkkik, с оригинальной версией `typing` находится, а вот `List` и `DefaultDict` в нем - нет.

Comment: [typing.py#L89](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/641279e6e51b5d2e10d3fbffe6330e47c94c4bb2/Lib/typing.py#L89) - вот же они в списке имен. Как нет? Вы уверены, что импортируете именно тот файл, который скачали с гитхаба?

Comment: @mkkik, да, точно. При переходе по typing из строки `from typing import DefaultDict, List` открывается файл, в котором перечислены эти имена. Почему не работает - ума не приложу

Comment: Что в выводе `python -c "import typing; print(typing.__file__)"`?

Comment: @mkkik `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\typing.py`

Comment: Это тот путь по которому вы положили файл? Или должен быть `site-packages`?

Comment: @mkkik, да, в site-packages нет файла с таким именем. На самом деле, если основной код рабочий, он выполняется без ошибок, просто пайчарма пишет `Unresolved reference`

Comment: Возможно, пайчарму просто нужен перезапуск (обновление списка доступных модулей).

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решился установкой последней версии PyCharm (2020.2.1)